# I can't convert to jpg using node sharp

Tags: node.js, image, sharp

I use sharp node (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) in a lambda node function to convert, crop, and white background images

**I tolerate various input formats, but the image output format should always be jpg.**

The problem is that in some cases sharp does not convert the image to jpg, when it happens is always with png images, it does not always happen, another problem is that sharp does not throw exceptions, ie the error is "silent".

Unfortunately I do not have the original image because I do not save this information, below is the code:

For crop:

```
image.extract(offset)
    .resize(width, height)
    .toFormat('jpeg')
    .jpeg({
      quality: 100,
      chromaSubsampling: '4:4:4'
    })
    .toBuffer();
```

To put white background:

```
image.flatten(true)
    .resize(width, height)
    .background(backgroundColor.white)
    .embed()
    .toFormat('jpeg')
    .jpeg({
      quality: 100,
      chromaSubsampling: '4:4:4'
    })
    .toBuffer();
```

Other cases:

```
image.flatten(true)
    .resize(width, height)
    .background(backgroundColor.white)
    .toFormat('jpeg')
    .jpeg({
      quality: 100,
      chromaSubsampling: '4:4:4'
    })
    .toBuffer();
```

I searched for answers to this and still can't find, has anyone been through this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set `force: true` on the `jpeg()` options. If you don't, sharp will respect the input format and effectively do nothing with the `jpeg()` call.

Example:

```
image.extract(offset)
    .resize(width, height)
    .toFormat('jpeg')
    .jpeg({
      quality: 100,
      chromaSubsampling: '4:4:4',
      force: true, // <----- add this parameter
    })
    .toBuffer();
```

Source: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/api-output/#parameters_3

Comment: [Docs](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#jpeg) say `force` is true by default.  Is this a recent update?

Answer (score -1):

Docs say `force` is true by default, but set this property is useful.

Comment: What changes if it's already true by default? Why do you specify it?